# How to resolve error: "[WDS] Disconnected!"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[image]

I'm currently getting started on ReactJs. However, I've come across the following error in the console which doers not show in the terminal:

> [WDS] Disconnected!sock.onclose @ client?64c0:70EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:49(anonymous function) @ main.js:356
>
> abstract-xhr.js:128 GET http://127.0.0.0/sockjs-node/info?t=1461853324372 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

It's looking for "sockjs-node" which I've installed locally and globally, however no change. Shouldn't it be searching the "node_modules" folder?

Here is my configuration:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");


module.exports = {
    
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: [
        "webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.0/",
        "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
        "./src"
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./public",
        hot: true,    
        inline: true,
        quiet: false,
        noInfo: true,
        stats: { colors: true }
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./public"),
        filename: "./assets/js/bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectrories: ["node_modules", "src"],
        extentions: ["", ".js"]
    },
    module : {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: "/node_modules/",
                loaders: ["react-hot-loader", "babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015"] 
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.gif$/,
                loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png"
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9].[0-9].[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff"
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9].[0-9].[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [ 
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development")
            }
        })
    ]

}
```

Comment: Your app is running on port 8080, but you're HMR is listening on port 80. Try this: `"webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.0:8080/"`

Comment: Thanks lux... now its getting the socket module. However still displays  "[WDS] Disconnected!"

Comment: Hm, my entry looks identical except I use localhost and not the local IP: `entry = [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/bootstrap'
    ]`

Comment: My simple react boilerplate: https://github.com/mikechabot/react-boilerplate `npm install` -> `npm start`

Answer (score 14):

I fixed it like this;

as-is :

```
  entry: [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9090",
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
    "./src/app"
  ],
```

to-be :

```
  entry: [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.0:8080",
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
    "./src"
  ],
```

Comment: The to-be part has a different port number, but for me the problem was solved just by replacing localhost with IP address.

Answer (score 9):

To me, solved when I created a file: `vue.config.js` in root project with content below:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
}
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-disablehostcheck): "THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED as apps that do not check the host are vulnerable to DNS rebinding attacks."

Comment: In newer versions, use: `allowedHosts: "all"` (see: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts)

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same kind of error, because my Webpack was configured to serve at `localhost:3000`, but I had a local port redirection in place from `80` to `3000`, and I was accessing the dev application using `http://localhost/`. But in Network inspector I've noticed that WDS was still querying `http://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/info?...` which was timing out.

Solution is to tell Webpack the "public" address of your app, in my case was like this:

```
devServer: {
      https: false,
      port: 3000,
      public: 'http://localhost:80'
    }
```

(Note: the `:80` part of the `public` is optional, since `80` is the default, but added to make it clear, that `3000` is the port being served and `80` is the port being redirected to it.)

(Don't ask why I simply not use `port: 80` instead, it's complicated. But I hope my answer will help someone like me one day.)

Answer (score 4):

## 2022 update

As mentioned by others, this is an issue with `webpack-dev-server`. The problem is likely a host or port mismatch in your environment.

The solution is simple - update your Webpack config (e.g. `webpack.config.js`) to allow all hosts:

```
devServer: {
  ...
  allowedHosts: ['all'],
  ...
},
```

As this disables important security protections, **do not use this setting in production** ([More info](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts)).

Comment: Maybe that bold sentence isn't quite right ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that you have not included the port number in url  `webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.0/`

Change This

```
entry: [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.0/",
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
    "./src"
],
```

To:

```
entry: [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.0:8080/",
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
    "./src"
],
```

Comment: This answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/53631238/5403449

Answer (score 1):

In our case the issue was due to a mismatch between the host name that `webpack-dev-server` was using to serve the asset, and the host name the application was running from.

Specifically, our local application was running from https://dev.resumize.me, but `webpack-dev-server` was serving the asset from `127.0.0.1`.

You can control the host name used by `webpack-dev-server` with the option `--host`. So in our case, we had to launch it with:

`webpack-dev-server.js  --host dev.resumize.me --https`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I was running my site through ngrok (a tunnel service). Knowing the --host option helps. But can I specify multiple hosts (e.g. localhost AND mytunnel.ngrok.com)?

Comment: @morgler I am afraid you cannot specify multiple hosts.

Answer (score 0):

In `development.js` file try to use the following settings for `dev_server`:

```
dev_server: {
    host: '127.0.0.0'
    port: 8080
    https: false
    disableHostCheck: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular and I use the webpack server as a dev-dependency. I was looking for an answer and couldn't find a suitable one for me.

**Note: This is just a workaround and not a fix for the actual problem**

open the following file

> YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js

in the method **onSocketMsg** , under the **function ok()** **comment the line reloadApp().**

This prevents the app from reloading continuously. This stops the application from reloading even if you make your changes. But you can always reload your browser manually and your changes would reflect.

Answer (score 0):

### This will be solved by Enabling Error Overlay,

`overlay:true` include one more property in  `devServer` object

```
devServer: {
    overlay: true,
    contentBase: "./public",
    hot: true,    
    inline: true,
    quiet: false,
    noInfo: true,
    stats: { colors: true }
}
```

> after change your webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");


module.exports = {

    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: [
        "webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.0/",
        "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
        "./src"
    ],
    devServer: {
        overlay: true,
        contentBase: "./public",
        hot: true,    
        inline: true,
        quiet: false,
        noInfo: true,
        stats: { colors: true }
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./public"),
        filename: "./assets/js/bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectrories: ["node_modules", "src"],
        extentions: ["", ".js"]
    },
    module : {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: "/node_modules/",
                loaders: ["react-hot-loader", "babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015"] 
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.gif$/,
                loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png"
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9].[0-9].[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff"
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9].[0-9].[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [ 
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development")
            }
        })
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the webpack config file : Modify devServer and add:

```
{ 
  disableHostCheck: true,
  transportMode: 'ws',
  injectClient: false
}
```

like the following and it should work :

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: "./public",
  hot: true,    
  inline: true,
  quiet: false,
  noInfo: true,
  stats: { colors: true }
  disableHostCheck: true,
  transportMode: 'ws',
  injectClient: false
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this:

```
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    https: false,
    port: 8080,
    public: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080'
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to change `webpack.config.js`

Try fixing in `package.json` (start **server** on port 3000 instead of **standard** 8080):

```
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --host localhost --port 3000 --content-base src --inline --hot",
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Could you explain why it should make a difference?

Answer (score -2):

in `index.htm` change path:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
   <script src="./main.js"></script>
```

to

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
   <script src="/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: This answer is downvoted because it is an answer that would only work for you and your current setup. It does not explain the WDS disconnect issue or how it can be fixed.