# SASS does not render in HTML using React with Webpack

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I have a React project with SASS using Webpack, my project compiles successfully, but does not represent the CSS effect in the HTML page in the browser. I compile it with `webpack-dev-server` command.

I have the following `webpack.config.js`:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            main: './src/scripts/main.js'
        },
        output: {
            filename: './dist/scripts/[name].js'
        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        module: {
            loaders: [{
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('dist/styles/main.css', {
                allChunks: true
            })
        ]
    }
```

and following `main.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import style from '../styles/main.scss';

ReactDOM.render(<h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
```

`main.scss`:

```
.example {
    h1 {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

and this is the `devDependcies` section:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get any error either in compilation, I only get this in console: `[WDS] Disconnected!`

Comment: Can you try replacing your loader object (SCSS) with this: 

ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!sass-loader")

Comment: Also you need to install node-sass. It's not there in your package.json.

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917722/keep-getting-wds-disconnected-error to avoid the [WDS] Disconnected!

Comment: Now I get no errors either while compilation nor in the browser console and also `scss` effect does not appear.