# Errors in browser console, requests to /sockjs-node/info?t=1555629946494

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I created a new site using vue-cli. I'm using the development server to serve the page. When I view the page in my browser, I see two types of errors show up in my browser console:

```
GET http://172.31.7.153:4000/sockjs-node/info?t=1555922702538 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
GET http://localhost:4000/sockjs-node/info?t=1555922708541 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I'm not sure what it means, or how/why it's being called, and it shows up repeatedly about every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I finally fixed it using the `devServer.public` configuration option.

Below is my `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        port: 4000,
        public: '0.0.0.0:4000'
    },
    publicPath: "/"
}
```

I got my answer from reading [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1616).

Comment: Thanks for the tip !

Comment: Just as a clarifying note the vue.config.js file does not exist by default, you might need to create it at your project root dir

Comment: For more info, check [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdisablehostcheck) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53631238/6736591)

Comment: See Nakamto's answer below for a simpler, better version

Comment: It's so frustrating that, as far as I can tell, this config option isn't listed in the documentation.

Answer (score 31):

To disable this warning just the config `host: 'localhost'` is needed.

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
  },
};
```

Create this file `vue.config.js` if not exist at root.

Note: The `disableHostCheck` config is [officially discouraged](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdisablehostcheck).

More info:

- Vuejs Doc: [DevServer](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver)
- Webpack: [devServer.disableHostCheck](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdisablehostcheck)
- [Fix Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53631238/6736591)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this with the following `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    https: false,
    port: 8080,
    public: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080'
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked in `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        public: 'localhost'
    },
}
```

I also tried to use `host` [like Nakamoto suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701328/11219058) but then the site was not loading anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a remote case and it does not apply to the OP, yet I bumped into this question and several similar ones after making the silliest mistake: **did you turn your Webpack (or other) compiler on?**

I wish I had found the hint so I thought I would leave a small life jacket.

[ Background: I missed noticing having forgot to run my `npm run serve` (it could have been `yarn start`). At the beginning of my coding session I did not launched Webpack's `bash` script, so I wasted quite some time trying to figure our what I could have done wrong last night. It had nothing to do with my code. ]